# How to show 20,000 list item in a single page report?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

A client wants to show 20000 list item in a single page report for SP 2013 on-prem application and for ordinary user. Restriction is you cannot increase threshold value, you cannot use iteration since you have to show all 20K data at a time.

Generally this will create trouble in the server (slowing down the server). How to overcome this?

How to show all 20K list item at a time in a single page report?

Comment: you dont want to increase the list view threshold?

Comment: yes we can't increase threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using Reporting Services?  You can set your site as a data source and query any list on the site as a dataset.  The only catch is that you cannot "join" lists together in a single dataset, although you could still include multiple lists on the report.

I once tried doing something similar with a Data View Web Part, that I would NOT recommend.  The page loads were getting bad enough with 5,000-10,000 records, 20,000 on a single page would be even worse.

I eventually replaced the Data View Web Part with a Reporting Services report which was a great improvement.  The report took a few seconds to load, where the web part took 30 seconds to a minute.

Answer (score 7):

The client wants to actually display 20,000 items on a single page, without paging? I cannot imagine a valid use case for this. No one is going to read 20,000 items. Tell them it's not possible. Then try to find out what they actually need and see if there is a solution. If they push back and insist on giving the users the capability to scroll through 20,000 items in a browser page, then at least realize that [you're not alone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg&feature=youtu.be).

Alternative:
Use power query in excel to pull the data into an excel workbook. Performance of a 20,000 row workbook will be fine, and the export, while slow, should work. (but again, the better route would be to try to find out what problem they're actually trying to solve).

Comment: Have you never met the: "We use CTRL-F for search" companies :)

Comment: +1 for the answer... Build them a nice search based solution that displays the data... CTRL+F sucks as a solution. If they want 20.000 in a browser... load items dynamically as they scroll down Breaks CTRL+F but that sucks anyway